# "Run-time error '-1698234242 (9ac7007e)' Automation Error looping through stores

Tags: vba, outlook

I don't know what this is:

> "Run-time error '-1698234242 (9ac7007e)'
> Automation Error.

Stopped in `Next oStore`

I reviewed all references.

The "shared Inbox" is named "WORKGROUP":

```vb
Public Sub NewInbox_Su()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oStore As Outlook.Store
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItem As MailItem
Dim lngCount As Long

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
For Each oStore In myNameSpace.Stores
    If oStore.DisplayName = "WORKGROUP" Then 
        Set myInbox = oStore.GetRootFolder.folders("Inbox")
        MsgBox myInbox.UnReadItemCount
        If myInbox.UnReadItemCount > 0 Then
            For lngCount = myInbox.items.Count To 1 Step -1
                If TypeName(myInbox.items(lngCount)) = "MailItem" Then
                    If myInbox.items(lngCount).UnRead = True Then
                        Set myItem = myInbox.items(lngCount)
                        If InStr(LCase(myItem.Body), "alarm") > Then
                            myItem.Categories = "Red Category"
                            myItem.Save
                            myItem.UnRead = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                DoEvents
            Next lngCount
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
Next oStore   '**

Set oStore = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myInbox = Nothing
Set myItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. On which line do you get the error? Also, I assume `**Next oStore**` is actually just `Next oStore`?

Comment: @Absinthe Yes, I wrote it in bold to mark that it stops there. I don't know where is the problem... I checked the available stores in my Inbox with other macro and I have a similar error. I think the problem is not in the code... but I cannot find the solution.

Comment: An automation error usually means the program no longer has an object associated with a variable. I don't know why you'd lose a folder mid execution or if that's the problem but you can check with `if oStore is nothing then`

Comment: @Absinthe I used this code for list the Stores but I receive this error: Run-time error -941162370 (c7e7007e) Automation Error                                                  Sub Test()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oStore As Outlook.Store
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    For Each oStore In myNameSpace.Stores
Debug.Print oStore.DisplayName
    Next oStore
End Sub

Comment: So yeah, looks like there's a problem with folders dropping out. I don't know why that would be, hopefully someone else can comment. The way to avoid the error is to use a for loop (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) rather than a for each loop, iterate backwards `for x = myNameSpace.Stores.Count to 1 step -1` and check for existance before actioning `if not myNameSpace.Stores(x) is nothing then`. I don't remember if the `Stores` collection is 1 or zero based, you may need `for x = myNameSpace.Stores.Count -1 to 0 step -1`.

Comment: @Absinthe Thanks! I didn't not get fixing the problem. I keep researching about that. If I get the solution. I'll type it here. Thank you so much!

Comment: .Stores is 1-based so the first store is 1

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue but with a slightly different error message.

When I was attempting to iterate through:

```
Sub CheckEmails    
On Error GoTo Errors

For Each Mailbox in Application.Session.Stores
    'Do some stuff with the emails in that mailbox
Next Mailbox
Exit Sub

Errors:
'My Error handling code
```

This works fine for 3 people I installed it on, but one particular PC was generating an error on the "Next Mailbox" line:

***Automation Error: -1110179567 (bdd40111)***

Which I've never seen before and doesn't throw up any hits on Google, and I haven't been able to resolve to an error description... I checked VBA references matched the other 3 machines, checked all the macro permissions etc. Everything was ok.

After going slightly crazy and stumbling on this question with the generous comment from @Absinthe, I changed my code to:

```
Sub CheckEmails
On Error GoTo Errors

Dim Mailbox as Object
For x = Application.Session.Stores.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Mailbox = Application.Session.Stores(x)
    'Do some stuff with the emails in that mailbox
Next x
Exit Sub

Errors:
'My Error handling code
```

Which still didn't work, but did give me a different error message on the "Set Mailbox = ..." line, which I **was** able to resolve to a "Permission Denied" type error description, when attempting to open one of the user's shared mailboxes.

Right enough, when I tried to open that particular shared mailbox in Outlook, I could not. As it happens, my wonderful systems admins had disabled that shared mailbox on the Exchange server without notifying users who had it open in their Outlook!

So I modified my code to be able to handle Session Stores that were open in Outlook but could not be accessed for whatever reason, in a slightly cheaty way, just by ignoring any error when trying to access that Store:

```
Sub CheckEmails
On Error GoTo Errors

Dim Mailbox as Object
For x = Application.Session.Stores.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Mailbox = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Mailbox = Application.Session.Stores(x)
    On Error GoTo Errors
    If Mailbox Is Nothing Then GoTo SkipMailbox        
    'Do some stuff with the emails in that mailbox
SkipMailbox:
Next x
Exit Sub

Errors:
'My Error handling code
```

This now works even if the user has a "broken" shared mail account (Outlook Session Store) loaded in their Outlook, which seems to have been what was causing my "Automation Error" when attempting to use that Store in a loop. Now if we encounter a Store which cannot be assigned to an Object due to an error, it just skips it.